# about session maintaining with php

Tags: php, session

Here's my `login_check` php file and `login_done` php file.
Before I had put in my Session functions, it worked well.
but after I had inserted some Session functions, it had stopped working and keeps resulting in "invalid login" even with a VALID ID and PASSWORD.

'login_check.php'

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once ('../config.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB['host'], $DB['id'], $DB['pw'], $DB['db']);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    extract($_POST);

    $q = "SELECT * FROM ap_member WHERE id='$user_id'";

    $result = $mysqli->query($q);

    if($result->num_rows==1) {
        $encrypted_pass = sha1($user_pass);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if( $row['pw'] == $encrypted_pass ) {
            header("Location: http://sovereign-recipe.com/member/login_done.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo 'wrong password';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'ID does not exist or invalid approach. Try again.';
    }

    if( $row['pw'] == $encrypted_pass ) {
            $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'YES';
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header("Location: http://sovereign-recipe.com/member/login_done.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'NO';
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
            header("Location: http://sovereign-recipe.com/member/login_done.php");
            exit();
        }

?>
```

'login_done.php'

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $is_logged = $_SESSION['is_logged'];

    if($is_logged=='YES') {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $message = $user_id . 'login success. session would continue with your logged-in info. start your surf.';
    }
    else {
        $message = 'your log-in is invalid. please, try again.';
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION);

?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>login result</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" >
        </head>
        <body>

    <?php
        echo $message;
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to debug check if the id and password are passed.

Comment: how to do debug check-  is there any good reference guide for it?

Comment: your query should be SELECT * FROM ap_member WHERE id='$user_id' and password = ''$encrypted_pass". and check num_rows() after this query

Comment: @SmithJackery. put exit() where you want to stop and open error_reporting(). devide your work in task like select query , result check etc.

Comment: You're calling `exit()` when the password matches. So you never execute the code at the bottom that sets the session variables.

Comment: @Bhavin my DB has a table with an user_id and password in a same row. do I need to make $q..select..where command with id and password simultaneously?

Comment: @Barmar thx. session related problem looks solved. but still the login_done page calls out "array(2) { ["is_logged"]=> string(3) "YES" ["user_id"]=> string(9) "darknight" } " these sentences even though my Echo never calls that messages. can I figure out why does it happen>

Comment: That's coming from `var_dump($_SESSION)`.

Comment: @Barmar I am a elementray level developer.(actually can't even called as a developer. just a studnet trying to provide some services.) do I have to keep with the var_dump session or is there any method to hide it from the user ?  thx again for your help.

Comment: `var_dump` is for debugging, it's used to show the value of an array or object in full detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach in your login_check.php

```
session_start();
include_once ('../config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB['host'], $DB['id'], $DB['pw'], $DB['db']);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

extract($_POST);

$q = "SELECT * FROM ap_member WHERE id='$user_id'";

$result = $mysqli->query($q);

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $encrypted_pass = sha1($user_pass);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($row['pw'] == $encrypted_pass) {
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'YES';
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'NO';
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
        //echo 'wrong password';
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'NO';
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
    echo 'ID does not exist or invalid approach. Try again.';
}

//You can to use here your redirect, then remove the previous
header("Location: http://sovereign-recipe.com/member/login_done.php");
exit();
```

I hope this help you.